# Regarding Map pin points that should display dynamically in iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, dictionary

hi everyone i have a mapview where i have to drop pins on the map based on latitude and longitude where i used to get that from a webservice can any one help me out how to get and plot it on the map and also if i have plotted any pin on the map that should be reflected in the web application through the web-services only.

Answer (score 0):

**Checklist for Adding an Annotation to the Map**

The steps for implementing and using annotations in your map-based application are shown below. These steps assume that your application incorporates an MKMapView object somewhere in its interface.

**1.**  Define an appropriate annotation object using one of the following options:

Use the *MKPointAnnotation* class to implement a simple annotation. This type of annotation contains properties for specifying the title and subtitle strings to display in the annotation’s onscreen callout bubble.
*(OR)*
Define a custom object that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol, as described in “Defining a Custom Annotation Object” . This type of annotation can store any type of data you want.

**2.**  Define an annotation view to present the data on screen. How you define your annotation view depends on your needs and may be one of the following:

If the annotation can be represented by a static image, create an instance of the MKAnnotationView class and assign the image to its image property; see “Using the Standard Annotation Views” .
*(OR)*
If you want to use a standard pin annotation, create an instance of the *MKPinAnnotationView* class; see “Using the Standard Annotation Views” .
If a static image is insufficient for representing your annotation, subclass MKAnnotationView and implement the custom drawing code needed to present it.

**3.**  Implement the *mapView:viewForAnnotation:* method in your map view delegate.
Your implementation of this method should dequeue an existing annotation view if one exists or create a new one. If your application supports multiple types of annotations, you must include logic in this method to create a view of the appropriate type for the provided annotation object.

**4.**  Add your annotation object to the map view using the addAnnotation: or addAnnotations: method.

REFER [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/LocationAwarenessPG.pdf) FOR COMPLETE REFERENCE.

Comment: thanks for ur reply bt my question is that i want to dynamcially add pins based on the latitude n longitude...

Comment: on userlocation i have to drop a pinview for example when user location is clicked i would like to navigate to other page and write some data over there and when click on submit it should display userlocation and also the pin that contains data

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-   in storeListArr store the value from web service

```
-(void)loadingMap
{
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    NSLog(@"storeListArr = %@",storeListArr);

    for(int i=0; i<[storeListArr count];i++)
    {
        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };

        region.center.latitude = [[[storeListArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
        region.center.longitude = [[[storeListArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue];
        region.span.longitudeDelta = .05f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta =  .05f;

        [self.mapView setRegion: region    animated:YES];

        MyAnnotations *ann = [[MyAnnotations alloc] init];
        NSString *str=[[storeListArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"store_name"];
         NSLog(@"Address %@",storeAddress);

        ann.title = str;
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
}
```

for call out

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{  
     NSLog(@"MKAnnotationView");
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        if ( pinView == nil )

        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MapPin.png"];
        pinView.image = flagImage;
        pinView.opaque = NO;

        UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,28.0f,30.0f)];
        [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MapArrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        for (int i =0 ; i< [storeListArr count]; i++) 
        {

            if ([[[storeListArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"]  floatValue] == pinView.annotation.coordinate.latitude) 
            {
                UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
                if([[storeListArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"imageUrl"])
                {
                [img setImage:[[storeListArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];

                }
                pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView =img;


                [rightButton addTarget:self
                                action:@selector(showStoreDetail:)
                      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
            }
        }

    }
    else
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"Current Location"];

       return pinView;
}
```

Comment: the problem here is i have to specify a comment on the pins and also i want to keep a callout,so when user clicked on a particular it have to navigate to other page and also i have to display an image and breif message abt it where all these images and description also come through webservice.and also at the same time i have to display the current location of the user.and when that particular user location is clicked it have to navigate to other page and a messgae will be typed there and wn came back that message should be displayed in the map at that user location ]

Comment: and also page should be map page should be refreshed always when user typed the message on the next page the info should be updated on the map view.how should i refresh the page always

Comment: thanks for ur answer elppa.but how can i reload the page after navigating from navigated page..that means after i come to home page

Comment: -(void)loadingMap fuction call in View Will appear, if my answer is help for your please acept my answer